# Real time updates on web using PHP?

Tags: php, publish-subscribe, long-polling, websub

I'm looking to implement a real-time collaboration on a document on the web.  Is there some sort of library that enables it in PHP? Something [similar to SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) which creates 'persistent connection' by using long-polling.

**update** found this library for [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/source/browse/trunk/publisher_clients/php/

Searching on the library name led me to [How to implement PubSubHubbub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847043/37759)

Answer (score 4):

Checkout pubsubhubbub

http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/

Comment: Found this library http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/source/browse/trunk/publisher_clients/php/